# How to put PreserveNoEOL's command to .vimrc

Tags: vim

I've installed [PreserveNoEOL](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4550) and I can use `:SetNoEOL` to remove EOL from current file.

But I do not want type `:SetNoEOL` every time I edit a file, I want to put it to .vimrc

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you always want Vim to leave off the final EOL character, creating what many people consider broken text files?! The plugin (I'm the author) wasn't meant for that, and I wouldn't recommend this unless you have good reasons, but it can surely be done via an autocmd in your `~/.vimrc`:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead * SetNoEOL
```

Comment: Thanks. It is just for current project I'm working on. It seems others using a different IDE(on Windows OS) and there's no EOL in all sources. I'm using vim on Linux, when I `git diff`, I alway got a `- no newline at end of file`.
Is it possible to match path in autocmd, so it only effects on that project?

Comment: Alright, for a single project that might be fine. You can restrict the autocmd to that path, see `:h autocmd-patterns`.